# Can "in order to keep" be used in place of "allowing"?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

A quote from [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) is as follows:

> An alternative approach commonly used in spacecraft is to divert surplus PV power into a resistive load, allowing the panel to operate continuously at its peak power point.

This quote causes a conflict, mentioned [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475063/why-is-it-desired-to-divert-the-surplus-pv-power-into-a-resistive-load/475066?noredirect=1#comment1204446_475066).

Can't we simply replace "allowing" with "in order to keep" in this sentence and let the meaning remain the same? If so, can't we reinterpret this claim as:

"Since our aim is operating the panel continuously at its peak power point, we divert the surplus PV power into a resistive load."

## Context

Above quote may not be understood without giving the context. There is a device called MPPT (Maximum Power Point Tracker) that does something¹ to extract the maximum power from a PV (Photovoltaic cell). Above situation refers to a state where the produced energy is greater than the demand. At this point, one has no choice other than simply ignoring the energy production² or wasting the energy actively by a resistor¹¹.

Wasting the energy production by either technique is an inevitable result at this point. Actively wasting the energy obviously causes the PV to operate at its maximum power point, yes. However, I expect the subsequent sentence explain the difference between those techniques, thus the main purpose. Here, the sentence starting with "allowing" is the subsequent one so I expect that it's the main purpose of performing the preceding action (actively wasting the energy).

However, the real benefit of wasting the energy by an external system that hasn't mentioned in the article [is that](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/475066/20285) the extracted energy helps the PV to cool down a little bit.

¹: MPPT to Photovoltaic cell is just like a vacuum cleaner to a carpet. If you keep the hose too far from the carpet, it can't suck anything. Similarly, if you stick the hose to the carpet, it can't suck anything either. There is an optimum distance between hose and the carpet. You will find it with trial and error, just like MPPT. With a varying vacuum cleaner power (analogy to the changing weather conditions), you have to re-adjust this distance periodically (assuming you can't hear the sound change).

²: Ignoring energy is letting hose lay down on the floor while the vacuum cleaner is continuing to operate.

¹¹: When your carpet is clean, keep using the vacuum cleaner at its maximum power by sucking dirt from the street.

Comment: _Thus_ means _in this way_, so it doesn't have the same meaning as _allowing_.

Comment: I edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I agree, in this context your replacement is valid (perhaps even preferable)

Comment: Almost "...allowing the panel to **operate**" would become "in order to keep the panel **operating**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. According to Wikipedia, ***Surplus PV power is diverted into a resistive load for the sole purpose of allowing the panel to operate continuously at its peak power point.*** [As I understand, to keep demand and production matched at all times].

Seemingly, this is a more desirable/efficient alternative than having to "shift the PV panel operating point away from the peak power point until production exactly matches demand."

Comment: You are correct. However, one has no choice other than "using a bomb" in order to "kill four people" in our context. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ceremcem I see. Please see my edit above. Apparently, in that context, "using a bomb" REALLY IS the only choice for maximum efficiency! :)

Comment: This is exactly [what I'm trying to say](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475063/why-is-it-desired-to-divert-the-surplus-pv-power-into-a-resistive-load/475066?noredirect=1#comment1204116_475066): This sentence is wrong because it expresses the wrong reason (keeping the panel operate at maximum power point) of an action (wasting the energy on an external resistor) because the [correct reason for that action is keeping the panel cooler](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/475066/20285).

Answer (score 1):

Using participle clauses , which are non-finite, that is have no associated subjects, is often legitimate, convenient and succinct, but can give rise to ambiguities in complicated cases like this one.

> An alternative approach commonly used in spacecraft is to divert
>   surplus PV power into a resistive load, allowing the panel to operate
>   continuously at its peak power point.

can mean either (probably the default reading, admittedly)

> [**A**] An alternative approach commonly used in spacecraft is to divert
>   surplus PV power into a resistive load; this diversion of power
>   enables the panel to operate continuously at its peak power point.

[the diverting strategy does the enabling], or

> [**B**] An alternative approach commonly used in spacecraft is to divert
>   surplus PV power into a resistive load, while leaving the panel to carry on
>   operating continuously at its peak power point.

[the astronauts leave the panel operating at full power].

While these probably do not differ significantly in overall meaning *in this case* (and it is not the job of ELU to comment on the feasibility of the operation involved), participle clauses need to be handled with care, and replaced if there is any hint of ambiguity.

.............

Your first suggestion doesn't make sense; do you mean 'adding *thus*'? Yes; adding 'thus' (or better, 'thereby') before 'allowing' disambiguates, forcing reading [**A**].

Your suggested paraphrase may get the main point across, but is by no means a felicitous precise rewrite.

Comment: "Your first suggestion doesn't make sense; do you mean 'adding thus'?" Yes, I edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is **[A]**, it enables the panel operate at its maximum power point.

Comment: The judgement '[[**A**] is] probably the default reading, admittedly' is from experience with such structures in English, not a knowledge of the physics involved.